# javascript, I'm new to javascript, from value from the drop-down list I need to change the class

Tags: javascript

please tell me how to transfer the values through the drop-down list to another page

```html
<select id="checkOpt" >
  <option value="Win">Win</option>
  <option value="Def">Def</option>
  <option value="Play">Play</option>
</select>
```

I'm new to javascript, from  value from the drop-down list I need to change the class

```js
const classColor = document.getElementById('classColor');
const checkOpt   = document.getElementById('checkOpt');
if (checkOpt.option == "Win") {
  classColor.classList.add('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
  classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
}
if (checkOpt.option == "Def") {
  classColor.classList.add('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
  classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
} else if (checkOpt.option == "Play") {

};
```

I tried a lot of variations, constant mistakes

*Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')*

I don't fully understand the logic and make a mistake,  I can't understand where exactly

Perhaps it needs to be done through for, but I can't find the information in detail anywhere

```
 <div id="classColor" class="myb-SettledBetParticipant myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost ">
```

located on another page

Comment: Where is your element with id "classColor"? It does not appear in the code you posted.

Comment: You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit toolbar to create a working [mcve] as long as you add in all the relevant HTML/JS/CSS.

Comment: that mean `document.getElementById('classColor');` return a null value. so this null value doesn't have any property, and the JS interpreter say I "Cannot read properties of null "....

Comment: <div id="classColor" class="myb-SettledBetParticipant myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost ">
located on another page

Answer (score -1):

selected value from the drop-down list to another page, you can use a form element with a hidden input field that holds the selected value. Then, when the form is submitted, you can access the value on the other page using the request object.
On the first page:

```
<form action="second_page.html" method="GET">
  <select id="checkOpt" name="checkOpt">
    <option value="Win">Win</option>
    <option value="Def">Def</option>
    <option value="Play">Play</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="classColor" id="classColorInput">
</form>

<script>
  const classColor = document.getElementById('classColor');
  const checkOpt = document.getElementById('checkOpt');
  const classColorInput = document.getElementById('classColorInput');

  checkOpt.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const selectedOption = event.target.value;
    if (selectedOption === 'Win') {
      classColor.classList.add('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
      classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
    } else if (selectedOption === 'Def') {
      classColor.classList.add('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
      classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
    } else {
      classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
      classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
    }
    classColorInput.value = selectedOption;
  });
</script>
```

On the second page, you can access the value of checkOpt and classColor using the request object. For example, in PHP:

```
<?php
$checkOpt = $_GET['checkOpt'];
$classColor = $_GET['classColor'];
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<select id="checkOpt">
  <option value="Win">Win</option>
  <option value="Def">Def</option>
  <option value="Play">Play</option>
</select>
<div id="classColor">Change my class</div>
<script>

const classColor = document.getElementById('classColor');
const checkOpt = document.getElementById('checkOpt');

checkOpt.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const selectedOption = checkOpt.value;

  if (selectedOption === "Win") {
    classColor.classList.add('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
    classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
  } else if (selectedOption === "Def") {
    classColor.classList.add('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
    classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
  } else if (selectedOption === "Play") {
    classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won');
    classColor.classList.remove('myb-SettledBetParticipant_Lost');
  }
});

</script>

check this maybe this will help you
```

Comment: the classColor id is located on another page where data is transmitted from the main page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).